# How to change username of Telegram bot or copy commands from old one to new one?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have created a testing telegram bot with some commands, but the username is not what I want.

But I found that the username of my bot is unable to change, thus I need to create a new telegram bot.

Is there any method to copy all the existing commands of old bot to the new bot, instead of creating all the commands again in the new bot?
**or**
Is there any method to change the username of the old bot?

Comment: Just replace the bot token in your script!

Answer (score 3):

After creating a bot with BotFather you should have got this reminder:

> By the way, when you've finished creating your cool bot, ping our **Bot Support** if you want a better username for it. Just make sure the bot is fully operational before you do this.

What may be unclear here is how to reach that "Bot Support". Luckily Hoi_a in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TelegramBots/comments/7gh6xr/is_it_possible_to_change_the_username_of_my_bot/) solved that mystery for us: just to go [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport) bot in Telegram and request the username change from it. I have done that recently and it took a couple of days to get a reply. I'll post an update later if my bot rename request actually succeeded.

**Update #1**: A month has passed since I posted my bot rename request to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport). They responded, that they need some time to make a decision and never came back. So, renaming a bot in this way at least isn't fast. Maybe it's even impossible.

**Update #2**: The support eventually renamed my bot! It took 44 days.

Comment: Thx for the info...I would rather go with a new bot ;)

Answer (score 0):

With my experience unfortunatly I say **no**, is not possible to copy commands from others bot and is not possible change the username of the bot, is possible only change the name of it.

This answer refers to the Bot API 5.7 (the latest release at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

### (Change the username)

When you create a bot using BotFather, it sends you a message like so with your bot token:

###### > Done! Congratulations on your new bot. You will find it at t.me/xxx. You can now add a description, about section and profile picture for your bot, see /help for a list of commands. By the way, when you've finished creating your cool bot, ping our Bot Support if you want a better username for it. Just make sure the bot is fully operational before you do this.
>
> Use this token to access the HTTP API:
> xxxxx:xxxxxxxxx
> Keep your token secure and store it safely, it can be used by anyone to control your bot.
>
> For a description of the Bot API, see this page: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

As stated, you can ping their bot support to get a better username for your bot. (Make sure that the bot is fully operational before doing this)

## Method 2

### ("Copy" all the commands)

Suggested by [@AdityaYadav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632834/aditya-yadav)

1. Create your new bot with the desired username
2. In your script, replace the old token with the new token (of your new bot)

You may transfer the description, profile photo etc. of the old bot afterwards.